# $\tau = \{U \subseteq X: X\setminus U \mbox{ is finite or } p\not\in U \}$ is not metrizable

Tags: general-topology

> Let X be a uncountable set and fix $p\in X.$ Define a topology on $X$ by : $\tau = \{U \subseteq X: X\setminus U \mbox{ is finite or } p\not\in U \}$. Show that $(X,\tau)$ is not metrizable.

Every metrizable space is first countable, so I want to prove that $(X,\tau)$ is not first countable. In my intuition, the most attractive point to show that this condition fails is the $p\in X$ itself. So let $\{B_n\}$ be a countable basis at $p$. Then, by definition of $\tau$, the set $X\setminus B_n$ is finite for every $n.$ For every $x\in X, x\neq p$, we have $p\in X\setminus \{x\}$, where $X\setminus \{x\}$ is open in $X$, as its complement is $\{x\}$, which is finite. Therefore, there exists $n_x\in \mathbb N$ such that $$p\in B_{n_x}\subseteq X\setminus \{x\}.$$

Taking complements on both sides, we have $\{x\}\subseteq  X\setminus B_{n_x}$.

I can't proceed from here. I need to find a way to argue, by the uncountability of $X$ and the fact that $\{x\}\subseteq X \setminus B_{n_x} $, that at least one of the $B_{n_x} $ will not be finite. How can I proceed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You started fine, but then you bogged down a bit. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $F_n=X\setminus B_n$, and note that $B_n=X\setminus F_n$. Let $C=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n$; each $F_n$ is finite, and there are only countably many of them, so $C$ is countable. Then

$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(X\setminus F_n)=X\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n=X\setminus C\,.$$

$C\cup\{p\}$ is still countable, and $X$ is uncountable, so $X\setminus(C\cup\{p\})$ is uncountable and therefore non-empty. Let $x\in X\setminus(C\cup\{p\})$, and let $U=X\setminus\{x\}$.

- Show that for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $B_n\nsubseteq U$, and conclude that $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is not a base for $\tau$.